# doing multiple labels in Visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

This is what I have for clicking on one label so it could change color, but I would like to know how to make it so the next labels will also turn red only if clicked.
In

In total, I have 48 labels If Seat1.BackColor = Color.White Then
Seat1.BackColor = Color.Red
Else
Seat1.BackColor = Color.White
End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same sub routine handle all of the seat label click events by casting the sender parameter as a Label:

```
Private Sub HandleSeatClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Seat1.Click, Seat2.Click, Seat3.Click

    Dim lblTarget As Label = CType(sender, Label)

    If lblTarget.BackColor = Color.White Then

        lblTarget.BackColor = Color.Red

    Else

        lblTarget.BackColor = Color.White

    End If

End Sub
```

If all of your seat labels are named in the same way (example = Seat5, Seat6, Seat7, ... , Seat48) then you can leverage AddHandler so you don't have to wire up the 48 labels with the Handles in the HandleSeatClick routine definition:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim intCursor As Integer = 1

    Do Until intCursor = 48

        Dim lblTarget As Label = CType(Me.Controls.Find("Seat" & intCursor.ToString(), False).First(), Label)

        AddHandler lblTarget.Click, AddressOf HandleSeatClick

        intCursor += 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Felt it's worth mentioning that even if all the labels aren't named in the same way, you could add all of them to the same container (groupbox, panel, etc.) and loop through all of the labels in the same manner as above.